# JavaScript expires headers can't be set to 12 months

Tags: php, javascript, html, performance, apache

I'm trying to make my website load faster. I used the tool `YSlow` to analyze the website and check for some improvements. My first step is to cache static files. Therefore I want to set the expires headers for a javascript file, but it doesn't work. I included the javascript in HTML like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//a.ph3nx.com/b.js"></script>
```

Then I changed my Apache2 httpd.conf file like this:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 minutes"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 12 months"
```

The problem is that the javascript file still has a expiring date of 1 minute. I hope you can help me, thank you!

**Solution:**

`ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 12 months"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try such code:

```
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 12 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 12 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 12 month"
```

Also u can cache your files using .htaccess:

```
  <FilesMatch "\.js$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
  </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you, the correct mime-type for my .js is application/javascript.